# Add element to array of records

Tags: javascript, arrays, records

Sorry I am new to JS. I have found references to .push to add an element to an array and using 'function' to define the structure of an object but I want to keep the code as simple as possible for teaching!

Here is my code:

```js
"use strict";
var ListItem = {
  field1: "",
  field2: 0
};
var DataList = [{
  field1: "",
  field2: 0
}];


for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  DataList.push(ListItem)
  DataList[x].field1 = prompt("item " + x + " Enter f1 data:");
  DataList[x].field2 = prompt("item " + x + " Enter f2 data:");
}
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
  document.write(x + ": " + DataList[x].field1 + " and " + DataList[x].field2 + "<br/>");
}
```

This is just the latest iteration of my trial and error.

I would like to create an array of a structured data type and then dynamically add elements to it. I have tried several alternatives to line 7 (DataList.push), such as DataList[x] = ListItem;

Sorry if this has been asked before but I cannot find a simple solution!

Comment: PS As I have defined 'ListItem' I would really like to create an array of that type of record, using something like:

var DataList = [ListItem];

I tried defining DataList as simply:

var DataList = [];

Then adding a new element using:

DataList[x] = ListItem;

Surely this must be simpler than I am making out! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two declarations at the top don't seem to do much, and you don't have to pre-declare your fields in JavaScript.. This should do the trick:

```
"use strict";
var dataList = []; 

for (var x=0;x<3;x++) {
    dataList.push({}) // make new object
    dataList[x].field1 = prompt("item " + x + " Enter f1 data:");
    dataList[x].field2 = prompt("item " + x + " Enter f2 data:");
}
for (x=0;x<3;x++) {
    document.write(x + ": " + dataList[x].field1  + " and " + dataList[x].field2 + "<br/>");
}
```

Though, it should be mentioned that this is a pretty horrible thing to do..

Comment: Thank you xs0. Nice solution for what I was asking. BTW those initial declarations are just me trying to find a working solution! Can I ask what would be a less horrible way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Well, I may have used a too strong word. If you're only figuring things out, then it's just fine. If you wanted to show something like this to other people, however, it would be very poor user experience - prompts otherwise block the page, etc.. A more "proper" solution would be, for example, to have two `<input>` fields and a button.. I really like React for things like this, checkout a React To-Do list tutorial of which there are many (and they're doing something very similar to the code above - adding stuff to a list..)

Comment: Thank you xs0 I understand. This is *not* the way I would create an interface on a web page! This is for introducing procedural programming to school pupils. I just happen to be considering using JavaScript for this introductory course. Introducing HCI elements early interferes with the pupils' ability to grasp the basic programming structures, I find it best to keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
const dataList = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  dataList[i] = {
    field1: prompt("field1 of " + i),
    field2: prompt("field2 of " + i)
  };
```

Some notes:

1) Javascript is dynamic, and thats the cool thing of it. Don't try to "init" an array, just use it as if it would be infinite.

2) all identifiers start lowercase, except they are constructors.

3) lint your code! That means add whitespaces wherever possible.

PS: to print the list:

```
document.body.innerHTML = dataList.map( el => `${el.field1} and ${el.field2}`).join("<br>");
```

or with an old style for loop:

```
for(const el of dataList)
  document.body.innerHTML += el.field1 + " and " + el.field2 + "<br>";
```